# How to get name of input like mvc's html's HiddenFor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to write a HtmlHelper extension method similar to HiddenFor. The difference is that I want to control what goes into the value attribute as well as tack on an extra attribute.  I figured I could just look at the source code for MVC, being as how its open source and all. But, unless I am blind, it appears that the strongly typed helper methods like HiddenFor, TextBoxFor, etc, are not included in the source code.

The method signature uses Expression> expression.

Given the expression how can I get the same value of the name attribute that HiddenFor would?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But, unless I am blind, it appears that the strongly typed helper
>   methods like HiddenFor, TextBoxFor, etc, are not included in the
>   source code

Everything is included in the source code, just [download](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781) it and look at `InputExtensions.cs`.

So to get the name:

```
public static MvcHtmlString FooBarFor<TModel, TProperty>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
    Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression
) 
{
    var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var fullHtmlFieldName = htmlHelper
        .ViewContext
        .ViewData
        .TemplateInfo
        .GetFullHtmlFieldName(name);

    // do something with the name
    ...
}
```

ModelMetadata metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData)

Comment: How odd.  You are correct. It is in the source code if you download it, but not if you browse it on codeplex. http://aspnet.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/68345#288010

Comment: @Mr Bell, the codeplex browse source is old, you should not rely on it.

Comment: That is certainly good to know. I had found other differences and just assumed the whole codeplex source was old. It never occurred to me that the download and browse features would be different